# group locations in location history which have same address while keeping order of locations

Tags: python, arrays, list, location, grouping

so I am making a location tracking app and I am trying to implement the location history, however, currently it is just listing all the locations. I want to group locations which are the same until the location changes.

I have tried to make a `psuedocode` version of this in python however nothing it working.

This is what I have tried in python

```html
l = [1,1,1,2,3,4,6,10,15,12,12,12,9,9,8,6,6,4] // this is what im using to test

grouped = []

for i, location in l:

  if(location == l[i+1] || location == [i-1]):
  
    grouped.append([location, location[i+1]])
    
  else:
  
    grouped.append([location])




    
   

// this is what i want the result to be

[[1,1,1],[2],[3],[4],[6],[10],[15],[12,12,12],[9,9],[8],[6,6],[4]]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [1,1,1,2,3,4,6,10,15,12,12,12,9,9,8,6,6,4] 
grouped = []
i = 1
intermediate = [l[0]]
while i < len(l):
    if l[i] == l[i-1]:
        intermediate.append(l[i])
    else:
        grouped.append([elem for elem in intermediate])
        intermediate = [l[i]]
    i = i + 1    

grouped.append(intermediate)
```

I executed your code.It was a lot buggier.
Hey Can you check this code if it serves the purpose?